# Finding out and adding map coordinates to database from street address?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I am receiving an updated database every day from my local MLS with homes listed for sale. Unfortunately, it doesn't include Lat/Lng coordinates, which I would like to use so I can create a map search. the only useful data I have is the full street address (with city name also). I know there is a google maps places API that can convert the address to coordinates, but this would be cumbersome to do on each property search, or each time a person zooms in or out on the map and the map needs to refresh. Is there a way for to populate my database with the coordinates from only the street address? (keep in my this is being done server-side so no javascript. just PHP and MySQL). Or perhaps a better way that I am overlooking?

Comment: There are daily limits on google places API. You could create a php script to make the request via address and save the resulting geography into your database.

Comment: is it possible to make the requests using PHP? isn't places a javascript library?

Comment: It's an API, you can make GET requests to it

Answer (score 0):

You might look to other solutions for the geocoding and then store the lats and longs in you DB daily as you update your db with new listings.

https://developer.mapquest.com/products/geocoding or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx

Depending on the size of your MLS the free tier might be enough calls for your data set.

After you have stored your lats and longs in the db, you are still free to use Google maps if that is your preference.